# Decompile APK, modify an activity and recompile to APK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, dex2jar

I'm trying to do something simple. I have an APK file, I want to change a certain variable value in a certain activity, and then recompile it back to APK so I can use it on my android device.

It's been days since I started with it and I can't find any solution for it.

I tried these approaches:

1. Decompile it with APKtool.
2. Open it with Android studio.
3. Change the value you want.
4. **Couldn't recompile it to APK.**

---

1. Decompile it with APKtool / Open the APK with 7-Zip.
2. Convert `classes.dex` to jar using dex2jar.
3. Open the jar file using luyten or jadx (jd-gui had an "internal error").
4. **Couldn't edit the files.**

---

On a different approach I can't remember how I did it, I was able to get to the activity files, but **couldn't understand how to recompile it to APK** again.

Please, if you have any idea of how do edit the `classes` and the activity, let me know. I have read lots of SO questions and google it so many times but I couldn't find any solution for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using Android apk tool you  can able to decompile the existing APK only. You can't recompile it. It will throw error

If you are going to convert dex file to JAR file and  JAR file to dex file that also won't work most of the times.

But one solution is available.. "DexPatcher". I tried this one but  got stuck in between do to lack of knowledge... You can try "Dexpatcher tool" it will be  good. If u got any idea please let me know..

Have a good day

Comment: Follow this link you will get a guide [https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/tool-dexpatcher-modify-android-dex-apk-t3060854](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/tool-dexpatcher-modify-android-dex-apk-t3060854)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [APK Studio](http://vaibhavpandey.com/apkstudio/). You can decompile/recompile apk using it. However, you cannot edit the source in Java. It decompiles in language called `smali`. If you need to just change a value, I guess this tool can solve your problem.

Comment: the tool comes with text editor. You just look for the variable and edit its value.

Comment: looks like the decompiled code is binary or something, I can't really find a readable class code as I could see on Android Studio. I found the variable name but not its value.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Use apk-editor.

Apk-editor is app in android 
That decompile and recompile apk

[apkeditor](https://apk-editor.en.uptodown.com/android)